# Why does adding formatting information to a f-string with tuple values raise a TypeError?

Tags: python, formatting, tuples, f-string

I'm trying to understand the following behavior of f-strings in Python:

The following line in which the tuple value is converted explicitly via `str()` works fine.

```
f"{str((1,2,3)):>10}"
```

However if I drop the explicit conversion the line raises a `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__`:

```
f"{(1,2,3):>20}"
```

There are no issues when there isn't any formatting given:

```
f"{(1,2,3)}"
```

I had expected that the f-string converts the tuple into a string automagically and then enforces the formatting requirements. This does not seem to be the case. Can somebody explain? Is there another workaround other then the explicit conversion via `str()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you experienced, there is some magic going on. However, it is *not* that every item is just being converted to string before formatting.

The TypeError explains what Python is trying to do: It is trying to call the `__format__` method of your tuple. But it fails because `tuple.__format__` does not expect a `>` argument. If you were to fine-tune the formatting of your own class, you could do something like this:

```py
class MyType:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return f"this is the value {self.value} formatted against {format_spec}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = MyType(6)

    print(f"{d:>10}")
```

**Output:**

`this is the value 6 formatted against >10`

So it would be up to your own `MyType.__format__` to generate and return a string according to the `format_spec`.

One native Python type that has a `__format__` method that deals with a `format_spec` like `>10` would be the string class. That is the reason `f"{str((1,2,3)):>10}"` works.

What you could do instead would be to use the `!` marker to convert the tuple to string - this is equivalent to using `str()` but less verbose:

```py
f"{(1,2,3)!s:>10}"
```

**Output**:
`' (1, 2, 3)'`

With one space added to the left as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by explicitly specifying the conversion to a string in the format portion of the string with a literal `!s` like this:

```
f"{(1,2,3)!s:>10}'
```

This is needed because the width specification `:>10` only applies to strings.